# Resolution of the $E_8$ singularity with a weighted blowup

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space, blowup

I am reading Miles Reid's notes on weighted projective spaces, and I'm a little confused about a particular paragraph (notes [here](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masda/surf/more/grad.pdf), page 8):

> A famous case is the $E_8$ singularity $X: (x^2+y^3+z^5=0)$, which is
>   naturally weighted homogeneous with weights 15,10,6. The
>   $\mathbb{G}_m$ quotient morphism $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$ defined by the
>   ratio $x^2:y^3:z^5$ has stabiliser of order 2, 3, and 5. The weighted
>   blowup $Y \to X$ (the graph of the quotient morphism $X \to
> \mathbb{P}^1$) is a surface having cyclic quotient singularities of
>   order 2,3,5 at the 3 points, giving rise to the Dynkin diagram of
>   $E_8$.

I'd like to see this very explicitly. I agree that $\mathbb{P}(15,10,6) \cong \mathbb{P}^2$, and I can see that the equation $x^2 + y^3 + z^5$ becomes $u+v+w$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$, with coordinates $(u,v,w)$, so I agree that $X \to \mathbb{P}^1$. However, I am having trouble writing the equations for the graph and observing the singularities Reid describes.

Here is what I can do:
The map $\mathbb{A}^3 \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{P}(15,10,6)$ is given by $(x,y,z) \mapsto [x:y:z]$, and the isomorphism $\mathbb{P}(15,10,6) \to \mathbb{P}^2$ is $[x:y:z] \mapsto [x^2:y^3:z^5]$. The graph of this map is
$$
\Gamma = \{(x,y,z) \times [u:v:w] \,|\, uy^3=vx^2, uz^5=wx^2,wy^3=vz^5\}
$$
Restricting to $w=-u-v$ I get the equations $(uy^3=vx^2, uz^5=(-u-v)x^2,(-u-v)y^3=vz^5)$. Taking partial derivatives, this appears to be singular everywhere. What have I done wrong?